# Chrome extenssion: Getting URL domain name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome-extension development and just read a sample "hello world" example.
Advancing, I would like to create a chrome-extension, which gets and pops the URL name to be accessed, on a pop-up window. How will I do this? I think this is more related to javascript coding, but still, how will I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's you meaning about "URL NAME"? for example, what's the name of http://www.google.com?

Comment: yep, that's what I mean

Comment: What's the part where you are stuck? Basically, there are three steps: Fetch the current URL, extract the domain name (I suppose that's what you mean by "URL name") and show it.

Comment: getting the URL/domain name on javascript.